# Does Ansible have a file or command that can recothe playbook execute history?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

Does Ansible have a file or command like `.bahs_history`/`history` that can display the playbook execute history?

If there is no default setting that can do that, is that possible to record ansible-playbook execute history in  Ubuntu?

I am very new to Ansible, any help is appreciated!

Comment: See the available callbacks `'ansible-doc -t callback -l'`, but IMO the best history is [Runner Artifacts](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy).

Comment: @VladimirBotka Thanks for your solution, I took a look at the ansible runner/call back you mentioned. They are too advanced for me:) I will keep learning and hope one day I can deal with them. Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

> By default Ansible sends output about plays, tasks, and module arguments to your screen (STDOUT) on the control node.

you can either configure [Logging Ansible output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html) as explained in the documentation or write results of certain tasks into a file.

**Further Q&A**

- [How do I get logs/details of ansible-playbook module executions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18807711/6771046)
- [How to use log_plays to generate a log file for playbook execution in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755132/)
- [How to log in a separate file per playbook in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135954/)